# CSS3 Transition shifts rotated element by 1px in Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-transforms

Safari fails to correctly render 180deg rotated element. In particular there are two examples when it can be shown (used Safari 9.1):

1. [Issue with odd width.](https://jsfiddle.net/mtkm1g7z/12/) You can see (look at the border) that the bottom element is shifted 1px right against its parent div initially and shifts more on transition.
2. [Issue with even width.](https://jsfiddle.net/mtkm1g7z/11/) It looks fine initially but also shifts 1px right on transition.

Here's css for even case (in odd it's just all widths and heights subtracted 1px):

```
.no-overflow-container {
  width: 518px;
  height: 368px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 368px;
  height: 368px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: margin 350ms;
  -moz-transition: margin 350ms;
  transition: margin 350ms;
}

.container:hover {
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.threed-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.faced-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

.rotated-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg); 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="no-overflow-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="threed-container">
      <div class="faced-item">
        HELLO WORLD FACE
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="no-overflow-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="threed-container">
      <div class="rotated-item">
        HELLO WORLD BACKFACE
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works quite fine in Chrome(52) and Firefox(47).

So any suggestions about how to fix it in Safari?

Answer (score 6):

I solved this using `will-change: transform;` (Safari 10)

https://jsfiddle.net/4hocy9qt/2/

Comment: Here to confirm that still in 2021 will-change is needed on Safari for smooth rotate.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at `backface-visibility`property, it could solve your issue:

`backface-visibility: hidden;`

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/